# It’s possibile with ARCore track an with e image?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, arcore-limitation

I’m trying to realize an AR application for my university course, that can track “Regoli”. Regoli are simply cubes or solid rectangle with variety of colors. Can I recognize the colors with image tracker?

I tried implements this in unity with image traker but he gave me errors, because it want a photo with Many point that can be track

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have no idea about unitys builtin tools, but you need some way to find your objects in the image. You would normally use some kind of "tracking markers" that give several high contrast edges to aid in detection. A simple colored cube would be very difficult to distinguish from a similarly colored background.